# how to remove "Eds" after authors name in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, revtex

I have no idea why LaTeX insistently puts "eds." after authors name in the `bib` file.
I simply use the following bibliography :

```
@PREAMBLE{
 "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}"
 # "\providecommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1}%"
}


@PROCEEDINGS{ref1,
   editor = "James Bond and others",
   title = "Proceedings of ..e",
   address = "Washington, DC",
   organization = "",
   publisher = "",
   note = "",
}
```

The output is like this:

> James Bond et al., eds, Proceedings...

Where does the eds come from??!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Adding “eds.” after the editors' names in normal for bibliography styles. Which one are you using?

Comment: If you are using REVTeX then presumably you are submitting to a journal requiring it. In that case, the BibTeX style is what they want: don't mess with it.

Comment: use `author = James Bond et al.` instead of `editor = James Bond et al.`

Comment: using author instead of editor, does not display any name at all.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Overlooked that this is a @proceedings. Well the "eds" is appropriate in this case. If you realy need to get rid of it, try another entry type (@misc, @book, ...) or edit the .bst file and include `format.authors output` to the `FUNCTION {proceedings}` next to the editor line.

Comment: Please post a *real* bibliographic entry. Using only your made-up example, it's simply not possible to tell if the problem is that you should be using a different entry type, e.g., `@book` or `@inbook` instead of the current type, viz., `@proceedings`.

Answer (score 1):

### Context

*Proceedings* are a collection of many conference papers and as such have many individual *authors*. The persons that take the individual articles and make them into proceedings are the *editors*. To distinguish the roles of authors and editors, the later are typically emphasized with *(eds)* or a variation thereof.

### Bibtex entry

The proceedings itself do not have an author, only the contained individual articles have that. If you are referring to an article within the proceedings, you have to use the bibtex entry type `@inproceedings`. If you want to cite the whole proceeding the "eds" should stay there.
For bibtex entry types see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX#Entry_types)

### Forcing Bibtex to Comply

Try other bibtex entry types that fit your needs. For instance `@misc` has authors, title, and a generic "howpublished" in which you can put all the rest. If this fails, or if you want to change the format for all entries of one type, you have to change or edit the bibliography style. They reside in .bst files (see [this](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/doc/latex/revtex/) for your case)